# Dart/Flutter null check on a map object

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a map from a json response, one of the itmes in the map is as follows

```
  isbn: (jsonBook['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers']?.length < 1 ? 'NA' : jsonBook['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier'] ?? 'NA'),
```

These are following conditions I am dealing with
The api response for some items may not have industryIdentifiers, when I am checking for null using ? it gives me error saying < was called on null, which is a possibility, how do I check that without breaking the rest of the checks (which is working fine)

To sum it up, I want to check if "industryIdentifiers" is a null, if yes return 'NA' if not null then check if any nested items "identifer" is null if yes return 'NA' else return the value for identifier.

This is the structure of JSON response:

```
"industryIdentifiers": [
                    {
                        "type": "ISBN_10",
                        "identifier": "1484799410"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ISBN_13",
                        "identifier": "9781484799413"
                    }
                ],
```

Comment: You've already demonstrated that you know how to use `??`, so use that: `(jsonBook['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers']?.length ?? 0) < 1 ? 'NA' : ...`

Comment: That work's well! There is always something new to learn, would you mind putting that as an answer, I will accept it and vote it.